# Send form data using cURL and receive JSON validation error from remote API

Tags: php, json, curl

Due to a few restrictions on my local web server, I am forced to process my comment form data in a remote server using cURL.

What I want to achieve is: send the form data by cURL to the remote validation script, the remote validation script checks user inputs for errors. If there are errors, remote script should send the "specific" error back to the local script. If there are no errors, my remote validation script should send email to me and also output a success message which I should receive in the local file and I will output same to the user filling the form if there is a successful submission or not.

**This is a snippet of my local file named Process.php**

```
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Comment = $_POST['Comment'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $api ="http://RemoteServer.com/Sendmail.php"; 

    $cu = "$api?Email=$Email&Comment=$Comment";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cu);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

**Here is also a snippet of my remote file http://RemoteServer.com/Sendmail.php**

```
    /**************************************************/
//-- data and error arrays  
$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data
/***************************************************/


    /*********** CLEAN INPUTS **************************/
// Create function to clean input
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

/******************************************************/

/********************************* VALIDATION ******************************************************/
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
/***************** DEFINE $_POST Data ************************/
$Email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
$Comment = test_input($_POST["Comment"]);

if (empty($Email)) {
        $errors['Error'] = 'Enter your email';

} elseif (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

 $errors['Error'] = 'Invalid email';

  } elseif (empty($Comment)) {
        $errors['Error'] = 'Enter a comment';

}  else {

//Send email to myself and output success


 $data['success'] = true;


}

if ( ! empty($errors)) {
        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

    $data['success'] = true;

        // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message


    }
    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data); 
}//--END IF NOT EMPTY POST
 else {
    $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
}
```

Now, what I hope to achieve is this:

inside my local file Process.php, I should be able to receive the errors from the remote file Sendmail.php and use it this way:

```
if (errors_from_remote_file) {

//--- Redirect user to error page to notify of form validation errors
header("Location: ./Error.php"); 
    exit();

} else {

//--- Redirect user to Success page if form successfully validated and email sent to me
header("Location: ./Success.php"); 
    exit();

}
```

At the moment, I have tried

```
if (isset($_POST))
and if (isset($_GET))
```

I have both inside my remote file Sendmail.php to retrieve the form data sent by cURL from the local file Process.php and I still can't get the form data.

I really need help on how to retrieve the post data sent from Process.php using cURL to Sendmail.php.

Once this is achieved, I want to also know how I can retrieve the errors from remote file Sendmail.php within my local file Process.php and use it to successfully redirect the user to the next pages depending on the errors or success output in the remote file Sendmail.php

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: First, you're sending input as param from the local script, but trying to access it via $_POST on the remote server. Secondly, you're not returning errors in the ELSE part of the remote script.

Comment: @djunehor If I use parameters, how then to retrieve in remote file? Secondly, the else part of remote file can only have one error which is if sendmail fails but that is not important as I can write that. What's important are the points I have mentioned in my question earlier.

Comment: _“I really need help on how to retrieve the post data”_ - start by actually _making_ a POST request maybe? The details on how to do that using cURL in PHP, you should be able to easily research yourself.

Comment: _“I want to also know how I can retrieve the errors from remote file Sendmail.php within my local file Process.php”_ - you have access to the response body in $result. Since you are sending JSON, the next step will then be to decode that, so that you have access to the elements inside the data structure again, and can base your decision what to do on those then.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for writing. However, English is not my first language and maybe I did not put it correctly. Of course I do know how to retrieve post data which is basic stuff. Check my remote file and see I already retrieve $_POST data. What I experience is I don't get to grab the data from the $_POST and I have no idea if I am passing the right parameters in the CURL request. As for the $result in the localfile, I have also attempted to decode the response with no yield yet.

Comment: Add this to your curl to send $_POST data: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($_POST));` You will definitely get the $_POST on the remote server. You can var_dump($_POST) to see if it gets post data and what's in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who has responded so far. For the `$_POST` error, I found out I was missing a `semicolon`. Once I had it sorted, I was able to retrieve the POST DATA correctly.

As for the JSON result from the Remote File `Sendmail.php`, I was able to output the errors or success notice by decoding the JSON object and used it to manipulate location to direct the user to upon error or upon success. Here is sample code used in my localfile:

```
   $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w'); //-- To monitor cURL procedure
$data = array("name"=>"ohidul","age"=>20);
   $string = http_build_query($data);
  $ch = curl_init("http://RemoteServer.com/Sendmail.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
   curl_exec($ch);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
 //-------------DECODE JSON ERROR FROM REMOTE FILE---------------------------------  
$RemoteResponse = json_decode($response);

if ($RemoteResponse == "Failed") {

    header("Location: ./Error.php"); 
    exit();
} else {

    header("Location: ./Success.php"); 
    exit();
}
//---------------------------------------------
```

I made basic errors by not watching out for the missing semicolon and I also thought it was a long process to read a few tuts on JSON. But, I glanced through a few lines on JSON and I was able to get this done myself. Frustrating initially but I am happy I learnt the hard way by learning on my own.